# How do I get a Node element from a Nokogiri::XML::Reader?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

The docs state that you can loop through the nodes with .each, and a node will be returned to the block. However, this is not true. The "node" that is returned is just an instance of Reader.

I need to get the Node object so that I can access the:

```
node.content
```

However, this appears to be poorly documented. At any rate, I can't find out how to do something so simple after 2 hours of trying. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Must you use `Reader`? Getting a node's contents is pretty easy without it.

Comment: It's a huge XML file, can't use a DOM parser.

Comment: "However, this is not true." You should be very careful about statements like that. All too often, it is true and it is your lack of understanding that prevents you from knowing differently.

Comment: "It's a huge XML file, can't use a DOM parser." Define "huge".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<eoxml
<x xmlns:tenderlove='http://tenderlovemaking.com/'>
<tenderlove:foo awesome='true'>snuggles!</tenderlove:foo>
<truth>echo chamber</truth>
</x>
eoxml

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(xml)

doc.each do |node|
  if node.attributes == {"awesome"=>"true"}
    puts node.inner_xml
  end
end

# => snuggles!
```

Comment: That node.inner_xml appears to be completely undocumented. Anyway, I see now that there is no built in way to get an object or hash representation of a subtree. I am surprised that such a basic function is left to the user of the library, it seems like something that would be very widely used. Perhaps I will fork it and add it.

Comment: "That node.inner_xml appears to be completely undocumented." Maybe you didn't read carefully enough. [inner_xml](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html#method-i-inner_xml)

Comment: `doc = Nokogiri::XML(reader.inner_xml)` # returns a document given the inner xml of a node from a reader

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be an older version of Nokogiri documentation on http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/ While its root redirects to the new nokogiri.org docs, there are a lot of deep links that show up on Google and Stackoverflow to the old docs.